# Magento Product Custom Option Error

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to create some custom option in our magento site for products.
when we create custom options and save product then error occured.

```
Error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '367-0' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_OPTION_TYPE_TITLE_OPTION_TYPE_ID_STORE_ID'
```

Please let me know how we solve this error.

we have disabled all cache type, but there is no solution for this error.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to programmatically create a custom option.

Comment: @Jürgen Thelen I am not create programmatically custom options. i have used advance product option extension. if i create custom option using admin panel manually then it is working fine but if i am import products using CSV file then it not add custom option under products.

Comment: Then I'd say you found a bug in this 3rd party extension. The error message you posted indicates that some code is trying to create an option that already exists. Without seeing/knowing the code in use even crystal balls won't work^^. I think you need to contact their customer support for help.